# Handling transactions when using Key-Value database

Tags: database, database-design

How do you handle transactions when using Key-Value database? Here's a [blog](https://blog.kvdb.io/2019/10/11/why-you-should-ditch-your-database-for-a-key-value-db) that explains the possibilities of using a KV database. The idea is interesting.

However, it does not cover how can you handle transactions? For example, you need to make sure when you store a certain value it comes with another value or else do not commit, which usually rolls back when there's an error.

For example, the blog shows this

```
users:<id> = {
    “email”: “user@example.com”,
    “created_at: “2019-09-25T02:03:04Z”,
    ...
}
users:email:<email> = {
    “email”: “user@example.com”,
    “created_at: “2019-09-25T02:03:04Z”,
    ...
}
```

Denormalized, but, how can you make sure those both entries are stored without transactions, also if you're going to delete one data, since they came in a same "transaction" should be deleted the same way (transactional also).

Comment: For every article advocating a key-value design, you'll find another berrarting it. It largely depends on your use-case and the specific database platform.

Comment: Here's the Wikipedia article on the [Entity–attribute–value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).  You'll get a more balanced view.